# Are there any kinds of glue resources for 3d gaming like loading meshes and scenes?

Tags: 3d, blender, 3dsmax

I have read the 3d Gaming engine books now and I am stumbling across tiny programs that load meshes and 3ds max scenes or blender obj files.

Whenever I try to load my created meshes, I am falling to load them. But when the sample projects load their meshes, they work fine. So it is the tiny things like my mesh obj data contained within them fail to render.

There had to be a good resource for common problems like these.
Anybody, please assist me.

Thank you, In advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I totally understand your question.  From what I have picked up, you are trying to write a custom obj file and load their content into some 3d program.

To debug your issue, I would recommand getting yourself familiar with the .obj file format (if this is the one that indeed interest you)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Then read the documentation associated with the 3d program you are trying to use to make sure it correctly support importing/exporting .obj files.

Comment: I have read Directx 9 books and they seem easy to learn. But when I shift to version 11 & 12, they seem hard to get to load meshes in right formats. Is creating a mesh so difficult while using the right formats. Why isn’t there any documentation help with these formats. How should I learn so many file formats.

Comment: I assume by creating a mesh "using the right formats" you mean representing your 3d data in the context of an obj file?

If this is the case here is the documentation for the obj file:
http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec

Most likely you don't need to know the specifics of every file format and in the case of proprietary file format you most likely won't be able to find any documentation.

Instead try leveraging existing libraries to import/export data from the different file format that interest you.